# Cannot merge two dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two function which returns two dictionaries.
In third function I've tried merge these dictionaries using `update` but I've got `None`result while printing.
Could anyone explain my mistake?

```
def first():
    dict1 = {
        one : [1, 2, 3]
    }
    return dict1

def second():
    dict2 = {
        two : [3, 4, 5]
    }
    return dict2

def third():
    return first().update(second)


print(third())
>>> None
```

I also tried this way:

```
def third():
    a = first().copy()
    return a.update(second())
```

By the way, this way doesn't work in Python 3.4:

```
def third():
    return dict(a.items() + b.items())
```

Comment: `.update` is **in-place**, it doesn't return a new dictionary. You could add e.g. `list(a.items())` in Python 3, but it seems awkward.

Comment: Also you need to *call* `second`, e.g. `d = first(); d.update(second())`. Currently you're just referring to the function object, not the dict it returns.

Comment: I think what you want is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression

Answer (score 1):

A bit modified version:

```
def third():
    d =  first().copy()
    d.update(second())
    return d
```